# javascript escape vs urlencode of non-ascii strings

Tags: javascript

- Context: HTML web page (jade/node.js/javascript)
- image url has strings with spaces/non-ascii characters
- I need to encode these strings either with escape or urlencode.
- as of now I am using escape to encode spaces specifically.

But I am not able justify/understand whether I should use escape to encode strings or should I use encodeurlcomponent. I tried reading some online blogs but not understood yet.

Any pointers to which one should be used under what circumstances.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `escape()` will not encode: `@*/+`
- `encodeURI()` will not encode: `~!@#$&*()=:/,;?+'`
- `encodeURIComponent()` will not encode: `~!*()'`

For more information, have a look at these questions:

[Encode URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript)

[When are you supposed to use escape instead of encodeURI / encodeURIComponent?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75980/best-practice-escape-or-encodeuri-encodeuricomponent)

Comment: +1, though worth noting that *escape* is not a normative part of ES5, whereas the various *encode/decodeURI* functions are.

Comment: @RobG That's the first thing said in the answer on the 2nd link `;)`